When was the Ashbringer added to the Warcraft lore?
In the original World of Warcraft the Ashbringer was a weapon a lot of players wanted to get their hands on. There were a ton of rumors on how to get it, though they all turned out to be false. The weapon itself was later available as the Corrupted Ashbringer dropping in Naxxramas and also became the Retribution Paladin's Artifact Weapon much later on.
I have always been confused about why people had been so hyped about this weapon back in Vanilla. Don't get me wrong, today this item has absolutely reached legendary status in the WoW community and lore, but what exactly did people know about the Ashbringer back in the day, that made it so sought after? Other legendaries weapons such as Frostmourne or the Doomhammer had already been firmly established in the Warcraft canon through the Warcraft strategy games by then, but what about the Ashbringer?
Was the Ashbringer ever mentioned or did it appear anywhere before World of Warcraft? The lore of this item goes back to the Second War, but as far as I understand all of that was established after WoW's release in works like the Ashbringer comic or the Chronicles books, as well as that one scene in the Caverns of Time. I couldn't find anything on it appearing in Warcraft II, which is the game that is set during Second War.
Did it originate in World of Warcraft itself then? If yes, when was it first mentioned and why exactly did it invoke such a hype? I know it is mentioned in Nat Pagle's Guide to Extreme Anglin', which definitely added to the whole search for the Ashbringer situation, but is that the first ever mention of the Ashbringer in all of Warcraft, or did people already know of its existence before that? Wowhead claims that book was added in patch 1.13.0 on the Classic Site and in patch 1.11.1 on the Retail Site, neither of which can be correct, as its earliest comment is from patch 1.4.2:


The first significant references to the Ashbringer are in World of Warcraft, around about patch 1.3. Some of the Shen'dralar Zealots in Dire Maul referred to a lost item known as the Ashbringer whose location could, with some difficulty and presumably a long quest chain, be pried from Prince Tortheldrin. Around the same time, two NPCs - Alexia Ironknife and Bardu Sharpeye - appeared in the Western Plaguelands claiming to be on the trail of a mage who had disappeared after crafting a powerful magical weapon for the Scarlet Crusade.
On its own, that doesn't amount to much. However, an early legendary item placeholder with the name Ashbringer (and an icon that doesn't resemble what it ended up looking like at all) had been datamined from the client, so players were primed to expect the Ashbringer to be a legendary weapon that would be obtainable by players. It was known that a new raid - Blackwing Lair - would be arriving in the near future and there was speculation that it would drop another legendary weapon.
As for what built hype when it wasn't the (thin) pre-1.11 backstory, I suspect most of the hype wasn't about having the Ashbringer, it was about finding the Ashbringer. The implications that there would be a globe-trotting quest chain involving some unlikely NPCs and out-of-the-way places, combined with the fact that there was no comprehensive database of quests so someone could stumble across the start of the chain at any time, made it exciting to speculate about what might be involved and might be required.

Can we say for certain that it wasn't in any of the Warcraft Strategy Games?

I really like your answer and must agree, the Ashbringer is basically the "Mew under the Truck" of the WoW community.

@TreeSpawned As someone who put a lot of hours into WC2 and WC3: no, the Ashbringer was definitely not there. Not in the game, not in the manual, not in the bonus CD of maps that they published in the late 90s.
